# Text of BufferedWriter should be bold

Tags: java

I was converting the text file into xml and want the textfile some text should    be in bold. If I write the below code the the tag also display in notepad file. Please give me the solution on it.

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                bw.write("<b> Company :</b>");
                bw.write(jobDescription.compnayName);
                bw.write("\n\n");
                bw.write("<b> Location :</b>");
                bw.write(jobDescription.location);
                bw.write("\n\n");
                bw.write("<b> About US :</b>");
                bw.write(jobDescription.aboutUs);
                bw.write("\n\n");
                bw.write("<b> Job Description :</b>");
                bw.write(jobDescription.jobDescription);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bw != null)
                        bw.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.error("Error in closing the BufferedWriter" + ex);
                }
```

eg: 
Compnay : xyz 
'Compnay :' in Bold and xyz in normal font

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HTML tags only work in specific programs that understand and can render HTML, such as web browsers.  Notepad is a very simple text editor that displays text only.  It does not do anything special with HTML markup.

Comment: Notepad does not display HTML. It displays the text characters of the file.

Comment: Is there any other way to bold the specific text without using <b> tag

Comment: No, Notepad is a plain-text editor, *without* support for any kind of formatting. The editor is *incapable* of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` is HTML formatting. You can't just expect to use it everywhere and have it appear as bold. Notepad has no concept of bold text, so it definitely won't do anything with those tags.

Comment: Yes..
Ok 
Thank you

Comment: Then what I have to do. If I want the text in bold

Comment: You'll have to choose a format that supports bold text, such as `HTML`. Then you'll need to write that file in the correct format, and finally view it with something that knows how to display this properly. XML doesn't support bold text (it's only data). Notepad doesn't support bold text (it's very simple). So write a HTML file and open it in a browser.

Comment: Or write it in [Rich Text Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and open it in WordPad. Linked wikipedia article even shows [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_example) of bold text.